# Get string between two sub strings with limitation

Tags: python, regex, string

I need help finding a substring using regex, starting with an example:

Given the following string:

```
test_str = "start: 1111 kill 22:22 start: 3333 end"
```

I would like to extract the string between start and end that doesn't involve kill:

```
wanted_result = (start: 3333 end)
```

Note: I need to get all matches of start blablab end that don't have kill between them

Several tries failed, the latest one:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'start:(.+?)(([^kill])end)',flags = re.DOTALL)
results = pattern.findall(test_str)
```

which results in a different result:

```
result = (' 1111 kill 22:22 start: 3333', ' end', ' end')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookahead based regex.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'start:(?:(?!kill).)*?end',flags = re.DOTALL)
```

`(?:(?!kill).)*?` would do checking before match a character. It checks that the character going to be matched would be any but it must not be a start of the substring `kill`.

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> test_str = "start: 1111 kill 22:22 start: 3333 end"
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'start:(?:(?!kill).)*?end',flags = re.DOTALL)
>>> pattern.findall(test_str)
['start: 3333 end']
```

Answer (score 1):

As a hint you may note that negated character class will exclude the characters within the character class **not** the words.For that aim you need to use a [*negative look-ahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

So instead of `[^kill]` you need `(?!kill)`.

And read this question about [regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!